# What is the difference between 2D and 3D array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

what is the difference between a 2D and a 3D array, from my understanding

**one dimensional array**

[image]

**two dimensional array**

[image]

but what i dont undestand is, what is a 3D array and how is it represented, if you are taking initiative ti explain me suing any particular language then please use python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A **one dimensional** array is an array for which you have to give a single argument (called **index**) to access a specific value.

E.G. with the following one dimensional array

```
array = [0,1,2,9,6,5,8]
```

The array at index 1 has the value 1. The array at index 3 has value 9. If you want to update the 3rd value to 8 in the array, you should do

```
array[2] = 8
```

A **two-dimensional** array is simply an array of arrays. So, you have to give two arguments to access a single value.

```
two_dim_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

If you want to update the 'second' value, you have to do

```
two_dim_array[0][1] = 'something'
```

That is because `two_dim_array[0]` is a one-dimensional array, and you still have to specify an index to access a value.

From now on, you can keep going deeper with the same reasoning. As any further dimension is another level in the list. So a **three dimensional array** would be :

```
3d_array = 
[
    [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8]
    ],
    [
        [9,10,11,12],
        [13,14,15,16]
    ]
]
```

Now to access a value you have to give .. 3 parameters. Because

```
3d_array[0] // is a two-dim array
3d_array[0][1] // is a one-dim array
3d_array[0][1][0] // is a value
```

I suggest you start doing simple exercices to get you familiar with this concept, as it is really 101 programming stuff. [W3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-exercise-11.php) has great exercices to get you started.

Comment: then, what is a 3D array? could you please explain me, please?

Comment: so, can we say that a 3D array is the array of 2D array? is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, a 3D array is an array of 2D arrays. A 4D array is an array of 3D arrays, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To declare a two-dimensional array, you simply list two sets of empty brackets, like this:

```
int numbers[][];
```

Here, numbers is a two-dimensional array of type int. To put it another way, numbers is an array of int arrays.

Often, nested for loops are used to process the elements of a two-dimensional array, as 
    in this example:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) 
    {
        numbers[x][y] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1
    }
}
```

To declare an array with more than two dimensions, you just specify as many sets of empty brackets as you need. For example:

```
int[][][] threeD = new int[3][3][3];
```

Here, a three-dimensional array is created, with each dimension having three elements. You can think of this array as a cube. Each element requires three indexes to Access.

You can nest initializers as deep as necessary, too. For example:

```
int[][][] threeD = 
    {  { {1,   2,  3}, { 4,  5,  6}, { 7,  8,  9} },
       { {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18} },
       { {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27} } };
```

Comment: so, for four dimension array, can i declare the variable like this
int[][][] fourD = new int[3][3][4];
int[][][] threeD = 
    {  { {1,   2,  3}, { 4,  5,  6}, { 7,  8,  9} },
       { {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18} },
       { {19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27} },
 { {1,   2,  3}, { 4,  5,  6}, { 7,  8,  9} }, };

Comment: No, for a four dimension array, you Need int[][][][] fourD = new int [4][4][4][4] . The number in [x] only make the size. Fout Dimentional Array are hard to imagine.

Comment: U get it now ? No worries. Best regards.